Using Presto for non adhoc queries
From this link:

While batch and ETL jobs run on Hive and Spark, near real-time interactive queries run on Presto.

This is a sentiment I have seen echoed elsewhere as well. I would like to understand what is the harm in using Presto for batch and OLAP jobs with fixed (i.e., non adhoc) queries? Surely if it can handle adhoc queries it should be able to handle non adhoc queries as well? Is it because it has high memory requirements and requires everything to fit in memory (just making a guess; I am not sure if this assumption is correct)? But then, isn't Spark also an in-memory execution engine with similar memory requirements? The documentation on these tools is pretty dense and I read conflicting documentation on different sites so asking here.

I would argue that distinction here is not "fixed" vs adhoc querying but the ETL/batch processing vs OLAP queries. Based on my knowledge/understanding Hive and Spark allow greater flexibility of what and how can be done with data in the pipeline while Trino/Presto is OLAP query engine, to quote from the docs:

What Presto Is
Presto is a tool designed to efficiently query vast amounts of data using distributed queries. If you work with terabytes or petabytes of data, you are likely using tools that interact with Hadoop and HDFS. Presto was designed as an alternative to tools that query HDFS using pipelines of MapReduce jobs such as Hive or Pig, but Presto is not limited to accessing HDFS. Presto can be and has been extended to operate over different kinds of data sources including traditional relational databases and other data sources such as Cassandra.
Presto was designed to handle data warehousing and analytics: data analysis, aggregating large amounts of data and producing reports. These workloads are often classified as Online Analytical Processing (OLAP).

So it should handle the "fixed" queries just fine but not everything can be easily expressed as SQL query. Also you are more depended on the query processing engine while the "manual" pipeline potentially can give you more control of what and how is processed (but you might not need it and Presto/Trino would be enough).

I see. I think I get it. The distinction is between building pipelines vs. adhoc querying. Pipeline is when you want to stitch queries and build a DAG out of them. so Presto cannot do that?

@morpheus in the nutshell yes. Presto is a distributed SQL query engine, that's it. "The distinction is between building pipelines vs. adhoc querying" - just querying.

check this though: https://youtu.be/5mWiyUfVwa0

@morpheus what exactly you recommend to check out there?

Trino includes support for fault-tolerant execution which is more suitable for ETL/batch workloads.
For smaller workloads or with careful management and sizing the default mode is perfectly fine for those workloads and used across many companies.
